# apt-get install not working [E: Read error - read (5: Input/output error)]

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management

I have an old problem (since a week) with **apt-get** which prevents me from installing and upgrading packages.
I have **Ubuntu 16.04**.

I am receiving this message on the top bar:

```
Error: opening the cache (E: Read error - read (5: Input/output error))
```

When I type on the terminal: `sudo apt-get update`, nothing goes wrong and it was completed successfully.

However, when I type  `sudo apt-get upgrade` or `sudo apt get install` , I get this output:

```
Reading package lists...    
Done Building dependency tree           
Reading state information... Error! E: Read error - read (5: Input/output error)
```

I have tried to delete the `/var/lib/dpkg/status` file and then update, but nothing change!

Comment: You have a serious problem with your disk.

Comment: which means what :) do you suggest any solution ?

Comment: Probably you need to replace it.

Comment: replace the package manager ? or the whole operating system

Comment: You can check the disk by running `sudo touch /forcefsck` and reboot.

Comment: I meant to replace the disk. Not some software, but hardware.

Comment: I have tried that, and unfortunately nothing change

Comment: I had the same issue on a virtual machine under Vagrant, other virtual machines are working fine, it seems an issue with Vbox drivers, so don't trust it's a storage related issue, if you suspect storage has an issue please issue dmesg command and review machine logs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This read/input-output error indicates **serious disk failure**!

**Back up all important data immediately** and look for a new hard disk.

---

You can find out more details about your disk health by checking its S.M.A.R.T. status.

Open `gnome-disks`, select your HDD in the device list on the left and click the hamburger menu in the top right corner. Chose *SMART Data & Self-Tests* to view the information.

Comment: Actually it is a new laptop (just 4 weeks of using) which I have bought and then I replaced Its windows OS with ubuntu 16 :(

Comment: As mentioned, check its SMART status and maybe run some of the offered self-tests. That will assure you whether it is a disk failure (very likely) or not.

Comment: I have opened the Disk app, and the assessment tells that: Disk is OK, 125 bad sectors.

Comment: Then you should run the self-tests. They're in the lower right corner of the SMART results window.

Comment: +1 from me; I got this after copying all data from a known-failing disk to a new one. Together with the other answer and a bit of DIY file fixing I got it to a state where it now seems to work fine again.

Answer (score 10):

Try this please as a last possible solution.  Open a terminal and type these commands:

`sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf`
`sudo apt-get clean`
`sudo apt-get update`

If this doesn't work either, then the hard disk problem is the most probable cause for this message unfortunately.

Comment: These commands are harmless, so no need to call them "last possible solution". But the error message does not suggest anything which could be fixed this way.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  It just eliminates the possibility of file corruption.  Nothing else.

Comment: Corrupt file content would produce a different error. If this method magically solved the issue, it would probably be because the file which causes read errors got recreated in a different, not defect sector on the disk. That way you do not fix the root cause though but only hide it and wait for it to bite you more severely.

Comment: The main reason why I proposed these commands was the fact that the guy does not state anywhere that he gets similar error messages from other apps too or that their system gives errors while starting etc.  They gave me the impression that only `apt-get` produces error messages.

Comment: Worked for me! No issues afterwards.

Comment: it worked for me! but i'm worried about the question answer **serious disk failure..** do i still need to change my hard drive? as *byte commander* pointed..